# Uncaught exception we running restful API using Slim Framework

Tags: php, android, web-services, slim, restful-architecture

I want to create an API using Slim for my android application. The API is very simple, i just want to save in my database data for an article. My code is shown below

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

/**
 * Verifying required params posted or not
 */
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}

/**
 * Echoing json response to client
 * @param String $status_code Http response code
 * @param Int $response Json response
 */
function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $app->status($status_code);
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}


/**
 * Creating new task in db
 * method POST
 * params - name
 * url - /articles/
 * 
 * {"error": false,
    "message": "Task created successfully",
    "task_id": 1}
 */
$app->post('/articles', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {
            //verifyRequiredParams(array('article'));

            $response = array();
            $article_image = $app->request->post('article_image');
            $article_video = $app->request->post('article_video');
            $article_title = $app->request->post('article_title');
            $article_main_body = $app->request->post('article_main_body');
            $article_tags = $app->request->post('article_tags');
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // creating new article
            $article_id = $db->createTask($article_image,$article_video,$article_title,$article_main_body,$article_tags);

            if ($article_id != NULL) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["message"] = "Article created successfully";
                $response["article_id"] = $article_id;
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "Failed to create article. Please try again";
            }
            echoRespnse(201, $response);
        });     

/**
 * Listing all articles
 * method GET
 * url /articles    
 * {
    "error": false,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "task": "Complete REST article by Sunday",
            "status": 0,
            "createdAt": "2014-01-08 23:35:45"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "task": "Book bus tickets!",
            "status": 0,
            "createdAt": "2014-01-08 23:56:52"
        }
    ]
}      
 */

$app->get('/articles', 'authenticate', function() {
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            $result = $db->getAllTasks();

            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["articles"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing articles array
            while ($article = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
                $tmp["article_image"] = $article["article_image"];
                $tmp["article_video"] = $article["article_video"];
                $tmp["article_title"] = $article["article_title"];
                $tmp["article_main_body"] = $article["article_main_body"];
                $tmp["article_tags"] = $article["article_tags"];
                $tmp["created_at"] = $article["created_at"];
                array_push($response["articles"], $tmp);
            }

            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });     

/**
 * Listing single task of particual user
 * method GET
 * url /articles/:id
 * Will return 404 if the task doesn't belongs to user
 * 
 * {
    "error": false,
    "id": 2,
    "task": "Book bus tickets!",
    "status": 0,
    "createdAt": "2014-01-08 23:56:52"
    }
 */

$app->get('/articles/:id', 'authenticate', function($article_id) {
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();
            // fetch article
            $result = $db->getArticle($article_id);

            if ($result != NULL) {
                $response["error"] = false;
                $response["id"] = $result["id"];
                $response["article_image"] = $result["article_image"];
                $response["article_video"] = $result["article_video"];
                $response["article_title"] = $result["article_title"];
                $response["article_main_body"] = $result["article_main_body"];
                $response["article_tags"] = $result["article_tags"];
                $response["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
                echoRespnse(404, $response);
            }
        });

$app->run(); 
?>
```

The above, is my index.php while my .htaccess is the below

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

The structure of my project is

```
include
  |
   -Config.php
   -DbConnect.php
   -DbHandler.php
libs
  |
   -Slim
v1
  |
   -.htaccess
   -index.php
```

I have uploaded my project in an Ubuntu Droplet i created in DigitalOcean, however when i run my project i get the exception below

Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' All Route middleware must be callable'

Is there anything i should change in my servers config docs?

Answer (score 2):

Slim is trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

In every route definition you have a second parameter with the value `'authenticate'` (for example in your `$app->post('/articles', 'authenticate', function() use ($app) {});`

You have to define the `authenticate` function somewhere before:

```
function authenticate() {
  echo "My authenticate logic!";
}
```

Take a look to the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/middleware/).